# How to pass values from php multidimensional array to json

Tags: php, json

I have PHP array rows that contains of two columns units,date.

How can i fill this funciton categories with values of column date and data with values of column units:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
...
   categories: ['08/29', '09/01', '09/08']
...
 data: [800,810,1000]
...
});
```

Comment: You talk about a PHP array but show JavaScript/jQuery code. How are you retrieving this PHP data?

Comment: there's nothing magical about json decode. it takes a JSON string and converts it into a native php equivalent. Once the conversion's done, you don't have json anymore. it's just a PHP data value/structure, and you access stuff in that structure like you would any OTHER php data structure.

Comment: Im filling array rows with values from mysql, there is nothing much to talk about. All im insterested how to fill those json arrays with my values i have stored inside php array server side.

Comment: then why mention json_decode? If you have a PHP array and want to convert it to json, then decoding is NOT what you want. json_encode()...

Comment: sry I got such advice to follow, since Im not familiar with json/jquery. What I should to rewrite in my question?

Comment: Example title: "How to Encode PHP Array to JSON"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first separate your array from your main array. example:

```
<?php
$main_array = array(array('unit1','unit2','unit3'),array('data1','data2','data3'));
$unit = implode(',',$main_array[0]);
$data = implode(',',$main_array[1]);
?>
```

then: assign it to your highcharts object like

```
$('#container').highcharts({
...
   categories: [<?php echo $unit; ?>]
...
 data: [<?php echo $data; ?>]
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PHP array called $deals for example, to encode you would just do

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var deals = <?php echo json_encode($deals) ?>;
 </script>
```

Hope this helps